# issues in sending email with attachment on ses

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ses

I have following code:

```
try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setSubject(emailSubjectTxt);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFromAddress));
    msg.setRecipient(
        Message.RecipientType.TO, 
        new InternetAddress("vik.ceo@gmail.com"));

    MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    BodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
    part.setContent(emailMsgTxt, "text/html");
    mp.addBodyPart(part);
    msg.setContent(mp);
    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachment.setFileName("SupportBySkill.pdf");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
            SendMail.class.getResourceAsStream("SupportBySkill.pdf"));

    attachment.setContent(bis, "application/pdf");
    mp.addBodyPart(attachment);

      // Capture the raw message
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    msg.writeTo(out);

    RawMessage rm = new RawMessage();
    rm.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toString().getBytes()));

    ClientConfiguration cc = new ClientConfiguration();
    cc.setHttpClientFactory(new HttpClientFactory() {
        public HttpClient createHttpClient(ClientConfiguration config) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient(new GAEConnectionManager(),
                    new BasicHttpParams());
        }
    });

    // Set AWS access credentials
    AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(
            new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXXX",
                    "XXXXXX"), cc);

    // Call Amazon SES to send the message
    try {
        client.sendRawEmail(new SendRawEmailRequest().withRawMessage(rm));
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
log.severe("Could not send email. with error" + e.getMessage());
}
```

However on google app engine this code fails with error: 
Could not send email. with errorno object DCH for MIME type application/pdf

Please advise what could be wrong. This error on debugging comes on following line

```
 msg.writeTo(out);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon SES has a limited list of allowed file types and attached file name suffix and MIME type must match. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/MIMETypes.html for the list of allowed MIME types.

I remember I had a hard time making attachments work with SES - in some cases MIME type was lost along the way (not appearing in generated raw email body), possible due to some JavaMail bug.

Anyway, here's the snippet that works for me:

```
byte[] bytes = getMyFileBytes();
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, getMyMimeType());
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
attachment.setHeader("Content-Type", getMyMimeType()); 
attachment.setFileName(getMyFilename());
multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [patched Amazon SES libraries](https://github.com/radomirml/aws-sdk-for-gaej) which work on GAE.

Comment: I am already using that and i am able to send emails without attachment.